# Multiple Signatures in Infopath

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, infopath

I have an InfoPath form I made that I would like to be able to submit to someone's document library in SharePoint to sign. I'm trying to create a signature process that doesn't use any third party digital signature products. There wouldn't be a workflow set up (unless you think that is the best way to do it). This form has to be sent around to multiple different people to sign, and there isn't a predictable route it always takes. This is why I don't think I could make a workflow.

Here's my idea. Each person has their own document library. If you need a specific signature, you upload the current state of the InfoPath form to their library. I want the form to be locked out to where only adding a signature is open. Then the person can save it to the next person's document library to sign and so on.

Is there any secure way to set this up using InfoPath forms and SharePoint document libraries? My first idea was to use the Ink Picture control on InfoPath, but I couldn't figure out a way to make it so that the next person to pull up the form couldn't simply erase what the other person wrote.I'm relatively new to both SP and InfoPath.

Comment: I realized you've asked this question 4 years ago, and I'm wondering if you've found an answer. I'm having the same conflict now and I'd really appreciate your help.